# How to create dynamic widgets based on json response

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How do I design the screen as shown in the Screenshot

[image: ScreenShot]

Here, in the screen, it has the option to swipe screen within the fixed content and screen are also created dynamically based on json response

Also, please help me out in creating dynamic expansionTile with multiple items as in the screenshot, and providing user to enter comments and store comment values based in each expansionTile

Comment: Check out FutureBuilder for displaying widgets according to the json response. Here is a [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: How do i add controller to `Textfields` created dynamically and capture eact `Textfield` values based on each `ExpansionItem`. Please help me out..

Comment: Create a List of controllers, and add them dynamically with the creation of each textfeild

Comment: Okay, How do i get values of each `TextField` based on each list item/index?